# How to enable Face Unlock on Samsung Note 3

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-note-3, smart-lock, face-unlock

For some reason, the Note 3 doesn't have the Face Unlock feature listed under Smart Lock (see screenshots below).

[image: Security Settings] 
[image: Smart Lock Settings]

<sup>Click on image to enlarge</sup>
Do I have to download the APKs seperately?

Comment: Do you have _Smart Lock (Google)_ enabled under _Security_ --> _Trusted Agents_ ? If so, try installing [Trusted face apk](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/trusted-face/trusted-face-6-0-1-android-apk-download/)

Comment: If [installing apk mentioned above](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134233/how-to-enable-face-unlock-on-samsung-note-3#comment169106_134233) doesn't work try flashing [SmartUnlock.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/themes-apps/gapps-smart-unlock-android-5-0-t2962765) in [Custom recovery](http://www.howtogeek.com/193055/what-is-a-custom-recovery-on-android-and-why-would-i-want-one/). (You may have to install a recovery first)